# Making a set by express server cookie be visible to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, cross-domain

I am new to Express and I have problems with sending cookies.
I made a simple express app that needs to set a cookie to the browser. This is the server:

```
const express = require('express');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

//app.use(cors());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', ['http://127.0.0.1:5500']);
    res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    next();
});
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());

const PORT = 9000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.cookie('testCookie', 'random value', {httpOnly: false, secure: false});
    res.send({user: "test", password: "test123"});
})

app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

So it successfully sends to the browser the testCookie on request with fetch:

```
let response = await fetch('http://localhost:9000/', {
            method: 'GET',
            mode: 'cors',
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
            }).then(response => response.json());
        console.log(response);
```

After the request the cookie is successfully send because is in the Chrome cookie tab but `document.cookie` returns an empty string. And also when i make request to a page the request doesnt contains the Cookie header.

How can I make the cookie to be visible to `document.cookie` and also to the browser to send his Cookie header?

Comment: What does this logs console.log(req.cookies)?

Comment: On server side, console.log(req.cookies) returns the cookie successfully but if I make a request to another page the cookie will be not sent with Cookie header in the HTTP Request

Comment: Have you tried setting cookie manually in the header of HTTP Request?

Comment: I can't set it manually because I can't get it in the browser - document.cookie return me an empty string and the purpose I need is to send an authentication JWT from the server to the browser

Comment: How are you making the HTTP request, I mean in node js you are doing it? Kindly post code of your HTTP request.

Comment: I make it in the browser with fetch API, the code is in the questions(second piece). In the browser, I send a get request via fetch to the server address and then I get the response as a Promise and the cookie is set in the browser successfully

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you to use an npm package: `jsonwebtoken`, [https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken.)

This way it's much cleaner:

```
const jwt = require ('jsonwebtoken');

// Create login logic here (check password etc.);


const token = jwt.sign(user, secret, expiration);

res.status(201).json({
   status: 'success',
   token
});
```

Try using JSON format instead of res.send since you have a body parser in place already and it's a best practice in modern APIs.